# Dual event in a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange issue, regarding

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

Is there any possibility that if I simply click it, a popup should open but if I try to open in the new tab by pressing ctrl and click or right click open in new tab it should open the URL which is in the href value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `e.ctrlKey` property to know if `ctrl` key was pressed when clicking on the link, and decide what to do (It wont do the redirection in the snippet because so doesn't allow it).

```js
var div = document.getElementById("div")

var popup = document.getElementById("popup")

popup.style.display = "none"
div.onclick=function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey){
    //redirect
    return true
  } else{
    popup.style.display = "block"
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div"> <a href="https://google.com">Yay</a></div>

<div id="popup">popup</div>
```